# call notify balloon message in windows 7 from cmd?

Tags: windows-7, cmd, notify, balloon

I need to create a notification balloon message in Windows 7 from the Command prompt with custom text. I have searched Google and found shell32.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can be done in [Powershell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730952.aspx):

throw an icon (`.ico` file) in a `c:\temp` directory or point that somewhere else.

```powershell
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")

$objBalloon = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon
$objBalloon.Icon = "C:\temp\Folder.ico"

# You can use the value Info, Warning, Error
$objBalloon.BalloonTipIcon = "Info"

# Put what you want to say here for the Start of the process
$objBalloon.BalloonTipTitle = "Begin Title"
$objBalloon.BalloonTipText = "Begin Message"
$objBalloon.Visible = $True
$objBalloon.ShowBalloonTip(10000)
```

#### Do some work

#### Put what you want to say here for the completion of the process

```powershell
$objBalloon.BalloonTipTitle = "End Title"
$objBalloon.BalloonTipText = "End Message"
$objBalloon.Visible = $True
$objBalloon.ShowBalloonTip(10000)
```

Comment: `'[void]' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.` `'$objBalloon' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`  Something's missing here

Comment: what language is this? PowerShell? The OP asked about cmd.

Comment: You can use this instead of relying on an ico file
$objBalloon.Icon = [System.Drawing.SystemIcons]::Information;

Answer (score 14):

Notifu is a free open source Windows program that makes balloons appear in the systray with custom text you specify. You can run it from the command-line, so it's easy to include it in a scheduled task or batch file.

http://www.paralint.com/projects/notifu/download.html#Download

Comment: any way to keep cmd window hidden?

Answer (score 7):

Here is a working compressed call to powershell. Every part of it is important, because it needs basic notification icon, and "visible" flag.

```
powershell [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("""System.Windows.Forms""");$obj=New-Object Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon;$obj.Icon = [drawing.icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon($PSHOME + """\powershell.exe""");$obj.Visible = $True;$obj.ShowBalloonTip(100000, """TITLE""","""NOTIFICATION""",2)>nul
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use [NirCmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) by Nir Sofer like this:

```
NirCmd.exe trayballoon [Title] [Balloon Text] [Icon File] [Timeout]
```

This does not seem to work for Windows 10. There you may use [Toast.exe](https://github.com/nels-o/toaster), which writes to the message area instead.

```
Toast.exe  -t "Title text" -m "Message"  -p NotificationImage.png
```

You have to turn on notifications for Toast.exe in the Windows 10 settings dialog
under Settings > Notifications & Actions