# Create Visual Notification Messages from Matlab in Windows, suitable for FileExchange (and without PowerShell)

Tags: windows, matlab, batch-file, popup, popup-balloons

For visual notifications in Matlab, I would like to create notification pop-ups or even balloons. [This FileExchange contribution](http://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23299-systray-set-get-system-tray-icons-on-your-computer-s-desktop) creates the balloons with Java, but unfortunately it is buggy.

I think the way to go is to call a batch-file with `system()`. There is a closely related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319884/call-notify-balloon-message-in-windows-7-from-cmd) but the answers are not feasible on my machine (PowerShell is disabled) or not allowed on FileExchange (Notifu binaries).

**Is it possible to visually notify users from Matlab with pop-ups in Windows without PowerShell or external binaries?**

A rather ugly approach, calling a batch and using the command window:

```
// popup.bat
ECHO Hello World
timeout /t 2
EXIT
```

Calling it with the `/MIN` command just shows the icon in the taskbar, which may be a little bit uninspiring

```
% popup.bat in search path
fullname = which('popup.bat');
system(['start ' fullname]);
```

Maybe it is possible to `ECHO` a string from Matlab, Change the windows size, position,... Or use `dialog()`, or a completely different approach? Probably even platform independent?

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/25925201/388389

Comment: Not sure about your executable limitations. `msg console "this is the message"` is an option?

Comment: @npocmaka cool to know that you can start java from bash! With your solution, it is possible to add a message box to the cmd window, which adds visibility, but the click shouldn't be necessary for a notification... I guess for using this approach to create a balloon, it would have to be done similar to the FileExchange solution by Yair Altman. With creation of an icon to which the balloon is attached. After all, it may be more reasonable to use Java directly in Matlab.