# How to get the installation notification in the task bar

Tags: windows, batch-file, installation, notifications, taskbar

I'm running silent(without user interaction and wizard) installations of few programs on my PC through batch files.

Is there any way how do I installation notification in the notifications tray when the installation starts and installed notification once the installation is done?

Also error notification if the installer encounters with any errors or faces termination in between the process.

Answer (score 0):

Notifu seems to do just what you want: http://www.paralint.com/projects/notifu/index.html

Comment: Is it possible without any third party tool. The reason why I'm asking because I want to deploy these batch files on a remote system and I don't want to install the application you suggested on 100s of machines. Can't it be possible within the windows system.

Comment: It's standalone, so maybe you can add it to the installation package and make sure it gets deleted afterwards. But it seems to be possible with powershell as an alternative: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319884/call-notify-balloon-message-in-windows-7-from-cmd (hey, someone recommends Notifu there too :)